# Python - Dataframe - split column data into new columns - explain what some of code means

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I am learning dataframes and wanted to breakup one column into new columns. I accomplished it with the 3 lines of code below (probably could be accomplished in one line but I wasn't sure how) by try and error, but I don't really understand some parts of the code I wrote.  I was hoping someone can explain what the "1" and "2" in the split and ".str[1]" and ".str[2]" at the end means.  Thanks

```
DataRow:
Customer 1234M01 123 BurOak St, 823-123-4567
Customer 5678M02 567 Young St, 819-1234567

Py_Cust['TEMP']=Py_Cust.DataRow.str.split('Customer ', 1).str[1]
Py_Cust['ID']=Py_Cust.TEMP.str.split(' ', 2).str[1]
Py_Cust['ADDR']=Py_Cust.TEMP.str.split(' ', 2).str[2]
```

Comment: If you try printing the values at each step you will understand by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '1' and '2' refer to the number of splits you are asking for.  So, for example, when you did

```
Py_Cust['TEMP']=Py_Cust.DataRow.str.split('Customer ', 1).str[1]
```

it split your data into two strings.

the `.str[1]` or `.str[2]` part refers to which item of the new strings you have created you want to assign to that column. Basically whenever you see square brackets in python `[ ]`, you are indexing an object.  For example, `str[1]` takes the second item.  Referencing the line above, since you split on `'Customer'`, `str[1]` will take the item after that, or the rest of the string.

```
"Customer 1234M01 123 BurOak St, 823-123-4567".split("Customer", 1)
>>> ["Customer", "1234M01 123 BurOak St, 823-123-4567"]
```

[Here](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) is some documentation for working with strings in general and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) is the pandas documentation for working with stings and dataframes